# How to prevent Jenkins Pipeline Shutting down NodeJS service upon completion?

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am attempting to deploy using a multi-pipeline set up via Jenkinsfile.  However, when the process is complete my server does not stay online.  I am able to start the command below manually and have the server stay online, but the server is not kept up when ran on the Jenkinsfile.  Is there anything I'm missing?

```
node {

  ... stages before...

  stage("Deployment") {
    echo "Deploying...."

    script {
      withEnv(["PATH=/opt/node-v8.0.0/bin:$PATH"]) {
        sh "nohup sh ./start.sh dev 8080 true &"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I use pm2: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: Would that replace nohup?

Comment: Yes, pm2 is your best friend :)

Comment: I seem to be having problems with having pm2 global, is there a way to run this locally?  If I use a local package, the results seems be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd / PM2 / Forever seem to be the only ways to keep the service running